# Help diagnosing scheduled post problem with transition_post_status

Tags: posts

I've messed with trying to get scheduled posts to fire a function for months and finally stripped things down to the following code to see what is happening. The problem is that a scheduled post will not show the wp_die.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )  {

    if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'publish' != $old_status ) {

        wp_die('STOP');
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

If I simply immediately click on post then the STOP shows but a scheduled post shows nothing and will publish. I've also tried simply wp_die($post); to see what is returned on a scheduled post and there the wp_die isn't fired.

Even forcing this to 'future' == $old_status does not work.

How can I diagnose why this isn't firing for scheduled posts?

I've tried var_dump as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `add_action()` only passes one parameter, not all three.  Change your function to:

```
    add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )  {

    if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'publish' != $old_status ) {

        wp_die('STOP');
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

**Edited to add:**

The `transition_post_status` hook fires after the post transition from future to publish has occurred, and calling wp_die() will not display 'STOP' for scheduled posts. Instead you will just prevent the remaining actions in `wp_transition_post_status()` from being processed.

Future posts are published with background scheduled events via wp_cron, so calling a function like `var_dump()` or `print_r()` will not be useful for debugging. Instead try using `add_option()`, `wp_mail()`, or XDebug bookmarks: jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html

Comment: Yes. Sorry. That was also in the code and I'll fix my OP. I cut it out by accident when stripping out the other calls after the wp_die. But the problem remains that wp_die shows for immediate posts but not scheduled posts. The question is how to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The transition_post_status hook fires after the post transition from future to publish has occurred, and calling wp_die() will not display 'STOP' for scheduled posts, but instead will just prevent the remaining actions in wp_transition_post_status from being processed.

Comment: Future posts are published with background  scheduled events via wp_cron, so calling a function like var_dump, etc will not be useful for debugging.  Instead try using add_option(), wp_mail(), or XDebug bookmarks: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html

Comment: Thank you -- I'll look into add_option. Would you modify your answer so that I can mark it? You've been very helpful but initially didn't answer. Your comments however were helpful.

Comment: @LPH - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I gave up for now - again. I've fussed with scheduled posts for over a year and cannot get a function to fire. I suspect the wp_cron is the issue. I marked your answer since it gave a good starting point to diagnose what is wrong.